# Angular 4 reactive form pattern

Tags: regex

I've been trying to write a pattern that validates this kind of matriculation number `HND/18/BAM/FT/033 or ND/18/BAM/FT/025...`

I came up with this pattern but it's not working

`... / "^[(NDY | (HND)] \/ [0-9]{2} \/ [a-zA-Z]{3} \/ [(FT) | (PT)] \/ [0-9]{3}$ "/`

I would really appreciate it if I could get an answer

Comment: You got an answer, did it help?

Answer (score 0):

Converting to an answer:

`^(HND|ND)\/[0-9]{2}\/[a-zA-Z]{3}\/(FT|PT)\/[0-9]{3}$`

Try it here: https://regex101.com/r/cjN4Am/1/

Tested [here](https://www.browserling.com/tools/text-from-regex) by inputting the regex returns:

```
HND/14/uad/FT/784
HND/24/Jqu/PT/425
HND/88/MJe/FT/398
ND/35/wXT/FT/306
HND/01/dGW/FT/973
```